# Interweave two files bash script

Tags: bash, sed, awk

I am trying to interweave two files that contain one sentence per line. I double spaced (`sed G`) the first file and I would like to incorporate the content of the second file into those empty lines.

How can I interweave both files so that the 1st line of file B goes below the 1st line in file A, the 2nd line of file B below the 2nd line of file A, until it reaches the end ?

Example: [line number|sentence number|sentence]

```
1  1 fileA
2   
3  2 fileA
4  
5  3 fileA
6  
7  4 fileA
```

Expected result:

```
1  1 fileA
2  1 FILEB
3  2 fileA
4  2 FILEB
5  3 fileA
6  3 FILEB
7  4 fileA
```

This is for a bash script: can it be done with `sed` or `awk`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 'R fileB' fileA
```

You don't need to double space the file first.

If you want to replace the empty lines though:

```
sed -e '/./!{R fileB' -e ';d}' fileA
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have the original unspaced files, you can use `paste` plus (GNU) `sed`.  I'm assuming there are no ^A (<kbd>Control-A</kbd>) characters in your sentences:

```
paste -d'^A' fileA fileB | sed 's/^A/\n/'
```

The `paste` command concatenates lines from the two files, and then the `sed` replaces the marker, ^A, with a newline. This works well with GNU `sed`; not so well with BSD `sed`.  You can also use `awk`:

```
paste -d'^A' fileA fileB | awk '{sub(/^A/, "\n"); print}'
```

Remember to type <kbd>Control-A</kbd> where the `^A` appears in the script.

You could also do it easily with Perl, which would only need a single process instead of two as here.

---

It also occurs to me that you could convert the control characters with `tr`, which is arguably simpler:

```
paste -d'^A' fileA fileB | tr '\001' '\012'  # octal escapes for ^A and NL
```

Answer (score 2):

If you un-double space the first file (e.g. with `sed -n 1~2p`), you can use `paste` with a newline delimiter (tested with GNU paste):

```
paste -d'\n' file1 file2
```

Testing with the files from *Birei's* answer:

```
fileA 1
fileB 1
fileA 2
fileB 2
fileA 3
fileB 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`:

Assuming **fileA** with data:

```
fileA 1
fileA 2
fileA 3
```

And **fileB** with:

```
fileB 1
fileB 2
fileB 3
```

Run following script:

```
awk 'FNR < NR { exit; } { getline lineB <ARGV[ARGC-1]; printf "%s\n%s\n", $0, lineB; }' fileA fileB
```

That yields:

```
fileA 1
fileB 1
fileA 2
fileB 2
fileA 3
fileB 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Another example:

**file1**

```
fileA 1
fileA 2
fileA 3
```

**file2**

```
fileB 1
fileB 2
fileB 3
```

**Command:**

```
awk '{getline a < "file2" split(a, b, FS); print NR, $2, $1 "\n" NR+++1, b[2], b[1] }' file1
```

**Result:**

```
$ awk '{getline a < "file2" split(a, b, FS); print NR, $2, $1 "\n" NR+++1, b[2], b[1] }' file1
1 1 fileA
2 1 fileB
3 2 fileA
4 2 fileB
5 3 fileA
6 3 fileB
```