# How do I horizontally concatenate text files in Linux using bash and a for loop?

Tags: python, linux, bash, scripting

So essentially I have two folders each containing 174 txt files. Folder1 contains files with the following names: file1.txt, file2.txt, file3.txt, ..., file174.txt

Folder2 contains files with the following names: file_1.txt, file_2.txt, ..., file_174.txt. The difference is only in the underscore. I want to merge each corresponding file (meaning file1 with file_1, file2 with file_2, etc.) so that I end up with 174 merged files.

The merge must be horizontal. Files in the first folder have the following structure

```
0
1
1
```

Files in the second folder have the following structure

```
30 58 102 120
12 120 214.4 1210
20 312 543.2 912.33
```

I want the merge to be horizontal so that the resulting structure of the next text file is like this

```
0 30 58 102 120
1 12 120 214.4 1210
1 20 312 543.2 912.33
```

My approach was to use the following bash script with string formatting, a for loop, and the paste command.

```
#!/bin/bash
# A shell script to merge our 174 txt files
FMT1 = 'Folder1/file%d.txt'
FMT2 = 'Folder2/file_%d.txt'
FMT3 = 'MergedFolder/file%d.txt'
for (( i = 0; i < 175; i++ ))     
do

      printf -v VAR "$FMT1" i
      printf -v VAR "$FMT2" i
      printf -v VAR "$FMT3" i
      paste -d ' ' FMT1 FMT2 > FMT3

done
```

I get errors saying FMT 1 2 and 3 are undefined and no such directory exists

Is there by any chance a better approach using Python? Thank you.

Comment: see this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12847488/interweave-two-files-bash-script

Comment: no need to jump through hoops with all the `printf` stuff, just use `paste -d ' ' Folder1/file${i}.txt Folder2/file_$[i}.txt > MergedFolder/file${i}.txt`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just `cd` in the directory where you find `Folder_1` and `Folder_2` and run this as bash script.

```
for ((i=1; i<=174; i++))
do

    paste -d" " Folder_1/file${i}.txt Folder_2/file_${i}.txt > ${i}_merged.txt

done
```

Comment: This worked. Perfectly. I was going to ask what is sed used for, but I see you've changed the code to a much simpler version which I understand.